# Scala - Abstract type in constructors

Tags: scala, implicit

Consider the following code:

```
sealed trait SpecieType
case class Mammal() extends SpecieType
case class Insect() extends SpecieType

abstract class Specie(name: String, specie: T) {
  type T <: SpecieType
}
```

However this fails to compile (line 5) because the abstract type is defined inside `Specie` class definition.

What do I need to change to make this work?

The reason why I needed an abstract type is because I need the type of its parameter at compile time (to perform implicit lookups for typeclass pattern). Basically, I need to do something like this: `implicitly[SomeTypeClass[Specie#T]]`, where `SomeTypeClass` is a typeclass that all subclass of `SpecieType` implements.

Comment: Why not `abstract class Specie[T](name: String, specie: T)`?

Comment: elaborating just a bit on @cchantep's suggestion, how about `abstract class Specie[T <: SpecieType](name: String, specie: T)`

Comment: Because in my case the abstract type `T` is hardcoded for every subclass of `Specie`, so having the syntatic overheard of using `SomeSpecie[HardcodedType]` everywhere is not what I want. All I needed is to be able to use `Specie#T` for implicit lookups, since the type is known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of the cases where the class body as constructor creates severe limitations. What you're trying to achieve is impossible per se.

To the best of my knowledge, there are two main alternatives. One is, as suggested by @cchantep in a comment, to use a type parameter instead of an abstract type member. The caveat is that it changes the declaration of `Specie`, which might make your life tedious in the rest of the program.

The other alternative allows you to retain the type member version at the expense of a bit of unsafety. This might be acceptable because you have an abstract class anyway, so only subclasses need to be careful:

```
sealed abstract class Specie(name: String, _specie: SpecieType) {
  type T <: SpecieType

  val specie: T = _specie.asInstanceOf[T]
}

class MammalSpecie extends Specie("Mammal", Mammal()) {
  type T = Mammal
}
```

You can re-enforce safety if you can bear to uglify the definition of subclasses of `Specie`, using an intermediate abstract class:

```
sealed abstract class Specie(name: String, _specie: SpecieType) {
  type T <: SpecieType

  val specie: T = _specie.asInstanceOf[T]
}

abstract class SpecieBase[U <: SpecieType](name: String, _specie: U)
    extends Specie(name, _specie) {
  type T = U
}

class MammalSpecie extends SpecieBase("Mammal", Mammal())
```

Since `Specie` itself is sealed, the only way to extend from `Specie` is to actually extend from `SpecieBase`, which is not sealed. `SpecieBase` enforces the safety that `Specie` cannot enforce itself.

Comment: Thanks. Though I ran into problems with context bounds and had to switch away from this, your solution worked flawlessly.